# How to Clear the Stack and close the application

Tags: android, android-activity

I want clear the stack and close the application by pressing on Exit Button in my application.So that when ever I open the application again i need to start the application from first activity.

I am using below statements but these statements are not working.I don't want to use Launch mode Single Task.

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closing all the previous activities as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("Exit me", true);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Then in MainActivity `onCreate()` method add this to finish the MainActivity

```
if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit me", false)){
    finish();
}
```

Also [check out this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16480930/2345913)

Comment: @Crusader-I am in 10th screen in my application.If I press exit button here i don't want to navigate to main activity but I want to clear all my stack and i want to navigate to android home and i want to start from splash when ever i opened the app again.and thanks for your above suggestion.